# Get all CPU usage using TOP command

Tags: linux, bash, process

Im trying to get cpu/mem usage from one of processes running on my machine. I'm using command:

`top -b -p <PID> > some_file.txt`

but it's giving me only the current utilization of one CPU. I know that in interactive mode I can use `1` to display all of my cpu's, but is there a way to achieve that in batch mode?

Comment: You can get them all from `/proc/stat`

Answer (score 4):

If you do "$man top" you can see " t option" for 4 way toggle. Use the option.

Steps to display cpu usage bar.
1. run top command
2. press 1 to list the cpu usage.
3. press "t" twice to display cpu usage bar.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this was kind of fast :) This issue can be resolved in following steps:

start `top` in interactive mode (form me, as I wanted to get the correct process to be shown - `top -p <PID>`
press `1` to display all cpu's utilization
press `W` to **save** the configuration

Now, as I found, `top` in batch mode uses file `.toprc` as a configuration file. When You save your configuration in interactive mode, You can use this file later on. So now, when it is saved, You can use `top -b -p <PID> > some_file.txt` and it will gather information about both cpu's utilization.

Comment: That shows you overall cpu usage, not for that specific process.

Comment: Overall + usage of process. That's why I'm adding -p to it.